# Finding the argument that gives the minimum

Tags: python, numpy, minimum

Im trying to solve a problem. I need 60 different values, and for each -let's say- 5 `A` values, there will be `Z` values from one to `A`. And I want to try all the possible outcomes of a function `g` and I can actually do it with the following code. But what I really need is also the corresponding `A` and `Z` values.
So let's say, for x=1 , I have A=1,2,3,4,5 and Z=1 ,1,2 ,1,2,3 ,1,2,3,4 ,1,2,3,4,5
and this makes 45 outcomes. What I need is the minimum of g at something like, g is min when

```
>>>"The x , A , and Z values that makes g min are:"
>>>[0.0001 , 3.0, 2.0, 0.015006343],
   [0.01263, 9.0, 7.0, 0.01609543],
..... and so on, 60 rows in total.


from __future__ import division
import numpy as np
import math

#*************constants************
b1 = 0.9917949
b2 = 0.01911
b3 = 0.000840
b4 = 0.10175
b5 = 0.000763
mu = 1.66057*10**(-24) #gram
c = 3.0*10**10  #cm/sec
me=9.1093897e-28 #gram
e=4.80320425e-10 #statcoulumbs
h = 6.62607004e-27
hbar=h/(2.0*math.pi)
lambd=hbar/(me*c)

Xvec=np.logspace(-3,3,60)
Zvec=np.zeros(0,'float')
minpos=np.zeros(0,'int')
gvec=np.zeros(0,'float')
minofgvec=np.zeros(0,'float')
minposvec=np.zeros(0,'float')

def gibbs(Zs,A,x):
        efe=me*c**2*(x**2+1)**0.5
        El=(4./3)*Zs*(-1.444)*Zs**(2./3)*e**2*x*(3*math.pi**2)**(-1./3)*lambd**(-1./3)        
        SEMF = mu*c**2 * (b1*A + b2*A**(2./3) - b3*Zs + b4*A*((1./2) - (Zs/A))**2 + (b5*Zs**2)/(A**(1./3)))  
        g=(SEMF+Zs*efe+(4./3)*Zs*El)/A
        return g

for x in (1,2,3):         #was -in Xvec, for simplicity I tried 1,2,3 
    for A in range(1,6):
        for Zs in np.arange(1, A+1 , 1 , dtype=float)
            g=gibbs(Zs,A,x)
            gvec=np.append(gvec,g)
            #minposvec=np.append(minposvec,gvec.argmin())
    #minofgvec=np.append(minofgvec,min(gvec))

    #minpos=np.append(minpos,minposvec.argmin())
#Zvec=np.append(Zvec,(1+minposvec))
```

I can find all values, I can write the Xvec (obviously) and the minimum of g to that x, but I can't find the true Z and A values at that minimum. I tried the `argmin()` command but It gives me result in all 45 range. So I can't extract the Z value. I appreciate all the help

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do. There are a few reasons I'm confused. First you have some grammar issues, sentences starting with but and and. Second you neglected to use JSON syntax in your list of lists and opted instead to use spaces, Z=[[1],[1,2],[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5]]. Third in your code you use the variable Zs to mean both the list and it's elements, which is inherently confusing. Please remember that people trying to answer these questions have 0 familiarity with your problem before reading the question and try to be as clear as possible with your code and details.

Comment: Additionally you don't want to try all the functions outputs, you want to try all the functions inputs, and in your code, (not that it even matters for your question) additional parentheses would make it easier to read for me personally. and you may have an indention issue in the code posted... the line ` minposvec=np.append(minposvec,gvec.argmin())` appears to have too man tabs in front of it.

Comment: Well, thanks for your comments. I'm not a native speaker, maybe that can be an excuse for my grammer. the line you are telling is where I have the problem. I am trying to find the position of g so I might calculate the Z argument that makes it minimum. But since Zs dimension changing with A, the index of minimum g does not really helps finding the Z value.

Answer (score 0):

What about replacing your last triple for loop with this? (**Edited**)

```
results = {}
for x in (1,2,3):
    A_min = Z_min = 0
    g_min = np.inf
    for A in range(1,6):
        for Z in np.arange(1, A+1 , 1, dtype=float):
            g = gibbs(Z, A, x)
            if g < g_min:
                A_min, Z_min, g_min = A, Z, g
    # Collect results
    results[x] = {'g': g_min, 'A': A_min, 'Z': Z_min}
# Print out results
for x, values in results.items():
    g = values['g']
    A = values['A']
    Z = values['Z']
    print('For x = {}, the lowest g is {}, with A = {}, Z = {}'.format(x, g, A, Z))
```

Comment: Thanks but it does not give the result I need. Since all g values calculated are smaller then g_min It only takes the last argument (which is not the "most" minimum of g's) and returns the same thing each time. I have tried modifying it by using vectors and adding each g to them, then finding the minimum among them. That works but again this time I can not figure out which A,Z combination gave that minimums for each x's

Comment: I don't understand. As `g_min` is updated as needed, surely its final value is the "most" minimum of all the returned values of the `gibbs` function?

Comment: g_min is needed for every x values. There has to be certain x's and whatever the corresponding g_min, at some A,Z combination. Then I need to what those A and Z's are. 
The real problem is finding the A and Zs at which the g is min. Since Z's dimension depends on A, argmin() brings me confusing results. I do not know how to find Z's and A's but I think I succeded to find the minimum g's for every x.

Comment: I did not fully understand your problem then. I have updated my answer. Does it now produce the desired results?

Comment: It seemed to be working at first but I changed my x and A range to the one I need, and it fails. I mean, I actually create an `Xvec=np.logspace(-3,3,60)` then in the range I use `for x in Xvec` but when I do that, even the resulting x's are not the elements of Xvec. 
Besides, I tried to see what happen when I try x in (0.0001,30,0.02) with A in range(1,50)
`For x =0.0001, the lowest g is 0.00149332055613, with A=50, Z=23.0` 
`For x =30, the lowest g is 0.00150330171989, with A=50, Z=19.0`
`For x =0.02, the lowest g is 0.00149332063154, with A=50, Z=23.0`
where I dont expect all A's=50